# Special sum of a list in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to sum the squared difference of two consecutive elements of a list. Let’s call a function doing this task `sum_sq` and then `sum_sq [1;2;3]` will return `(1-2)^2 + (2-3)^2 = 2`. I will for now only input a list of at least 2 elements so I don't have to handle empty list case. Here is my thought:

```
let sum_sq_2elts x y = match x y with
|x::y -> (x - y) * (x - y)

let rec sum_sqrdiffs sum_sq = match sum_sq with
|x1::x2::[] -> (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)
|x::y::z -> sum_sq_2elts x y + sum_sqrdiffs z
```

I got an error message saying that `Error: This expression has type int list but an expression was expected of type int`. Why is that?
Thanks for your input in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `x::y`, `y` must be a list. But after the arrow, you call `(x - y)`; here `y` must be an integer. This is your inconsistency.
Why are you trying to use match and lists? your function is simply:

```
let sum_squared_difference x y = (x - y) * (x - y)
```

---

> Even when I fixed that, I have a new error [...] How can I approach this?

First, your error:

```
Here is an example of a case that is not matched: ...
```

OCaml expects pattern matching to be exhaustive: every possible kinds of values that are represented by the type must be taken into account. For a list, you have either en empty list [], or the list made of `x` followed by a sublist `xs`, written `x::xs`. In your function, what should happen when the list is empty? what should happend if there is only one element in it? Thoses cases are undefined.

How to proceed? Let's go back from the beginning and consider all possible cases. Note however that if you must combine 4 elements:

```
[1; 2; 3; 4]
```

You are going to combine those pairs:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

And you will obtain a list of 3 elements.

- if the list is empty, return an empty list
- when the list as at least one element, it can be decomposed as `x::xs`:

  - `xs` might be empty, in which case you do not have a next element and need to return an empty list. This is where you go from N total elements to N-1.
  - `xs` is otherwise not empty, and you can combine `x` and the head of `xs` to compute the returned value value.

This should help you consider all possible cases. You then need to call the function recursively.

Comment: Even when I fixed that, I have a new error "Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(_::[]|[])
val sum_sqrdiffs : int list -> int = <fun>". How can I approach this?

Comment: Raise an `Invalid_argument` exception in that scenario, as the input list should not be less than two elements.